# Problems installing TensorFlow on Windows (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using `Python 3.6` from `Anaconda 4.3.1` on Windows 10. I'm trying to install `TensorFlow` using the following command:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Requirement 'tensorflow-1.1.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
tensorflow-1.1.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I tried to download the file `tensorflow-1.1.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` and then ran the command `pip install "tensorflow-1.1.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"` but I still got the same error.

How do I go about installing `TensorFlow` on my machine?

Comment: Officially only Python 3.5 is supported on Windows at the moment. See [discussion on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999). Sorry you ran into this!

Comment: Does that mean I should uninstall `Anaconda 4.3.1` and install just `Python 3.5`?

Comment: Anaconda should be fine, it looks like it supports multiple Python versions. You'll just need to [create a Python 3.5 environment](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html#create-a-python-3-5-environment).